# Conversão de datas no SSIS (Visual Studio)

Tags: ssis

Como faço para converter smalldatetime para date?

Por exemplo:

de **2019-04-29 16:19:00** para **2019-04-29**?
Ou deixar as partes de hora, minuto e segundo zeradas (assim: **2019-04-29 00:00:00**)?

Comment: Vê se te ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807895/19527215

Comment: Grato, mas não entendi como fazer. Consegui de outra maneira: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/ssis-expression-convert-date-to-string2 Alterei o tipo de data da tabela de destino para date e funcionou.